# LWP response JSON values are empty

Tags: json, curl, lwp-useragent

I'm trying to run GET method using LWP and CURL (unix command) to get the content in JSON format, I'm seeing the complete content only in CURL command but the LWP response is showing valid JSON but with empty values.

**REQUEST**

> LWP

```
   my $ua= LWP::UserAgent->new();
   my $host='https://sample.com/iersiefhsiof';
   $ua->default_header('Content-Type' => 'application/json');
   $ua->default_header('Authorization' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXxx');
   $ua->default_header('Accept' => 'application/json');
   my $response=$ua->get($host);
   $res=$response->content();
   print ($res);
```

> CURL

```
curl  -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H 'Authorization:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' -ikL 'https://sample.com/iersiefhsiof'
```

**RESPONSE**

> LWP

```
{
    "id":"",
    "state":"",
    "category":"",
    "severity":"",}'`
```

> CURL

```
  `{"id":"iersiefhsiof","state":"open","category":"App","severity":"minor",}'`
```

Please help me to understand what I'm missing in LWP request to get the complete response content.

Comment: I forget to mention, that I'm also sending some custom header 'x-inf-route-key'=>'GetID', please let me know whether LWP is having different way of sending that custom headers.

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed now !

As per Header.pm , I should use ":" for custom header field name , if I'm not using that then it is converting the first characters as Uppercase and hence the header is missed.

```
    unless ($field =~ /^:/) {
    $field =~ tr/_/-/ if $TRANSLATE_UNDERSCORE;
    my $old = $field;
    $field = lc $field;
    unless($standard_case{$field} || $self->{'::std_case'}{$field}) {
        # generate a %std_case entry for this field
        **$old =~ s/\b(\w)/\u$1/g;**
        $self->{'::std_case'}{$field} = $old;
    }
    }
```

Refer: https://github.com/libwww-perl/HTTP-Message/blob/master/lib/HTTP/Headers.pm

```
':x-inf-route-key'=>'GetID'
```

Thanks :)